# How do you take this multivector derivative that has a nested variable?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I want to compute the multivector derivative $\partial_\psi$ of $\Omega_B\cdot \mathcal{I}(\Omega_B)$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is a function that is linear in bivectors, $\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B) = \int d^3x \rho(x) x\wedge (x\cdot \Omega_B)$. $\psi$ is an even multivector in 3D space (so it contains scalar and bivector terms). $\Omega_B$ is a function of $\psi$, $\Omega_B\equiv -\psi^\dagger \dot{\psi} + \dot{\psi}^\dagger \psi$. $\Omega_B$ is a bivector because the second term is the negative reverse of the first term. The overdot signifies time derivative and the dagger signifies reverse. This is for a Lagrangian method so we are treating $\dot{\psi}$ and $\dot{\psi}^\dagger$ as constants. I use $\hat{\partial}$ instead of $\partial$ when a specific term is being operated on. This question relates to the geometric algebra Lagrangian for rigid body motion.

What I have so far:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_\psi \Omega_B\cdot (\Omega_B) &= \partial_\psi \langle \Omega_B \mathcal{I}(\Omega_B) \rangle \\
&= \hat{\partial}_\psi\langle\hat{ \Omega}_B \mathcal{I}((\Omega_B)\rangle + \hat{\partial}_\psi\langle \Omega_B \hat{\mathcal{I}(}(\Omega_B) \rangle \\
\end{align}
$$

The first term is:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\partial}_\psi\langle\hat{ \Omega}_B \mathcal{I}(\Omega_B)\rangle &= \hat{\partial}_\psi \langle -\hat{\psi}^\dagger \dot{\psi}\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B) + \dot{\psi}^\dagger\hat{\psi} \mathcal{I}(\Omega_B) \rangle \\
 &= \hat{\partial}_\psi \langle -\hat{\psi}^\dagger \dot{\psi}\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B) + \hat{\psi} \mathcal{I}(\Omega_B) \dot{\psi}^\dagger\rangle \\
&= -(\dot{\psi}\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B))^\dagger + \mathcal{I}(\Omega_B)\dot{\psi}^\dagger \\
&= 2\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B)\dot{\psi}^\dagger
\end{align}
$$
where I used $\Omega_B^\dagger = -\Omega_B$.

How is the $\hat{\partial}_\psi\langle \Omega_B \hat{\mathcal{I}}(\Omega_B) \rangle$ term calculated? This is *also* supposed to end up as $2\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B)\dot{\psi}^\dagger$.

Comment: I'm guessing that the use of an adjoint will lead to an elegant solution for the second term, but not sure how to formulate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second term is:

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\partial}_\psi\langle \Omega_B \hat{\mathcal{I}}(\Omega_B) \rangle 
&= \hat{\partial}_\psi \langle \hat{\mathcal{I}}(\Omega_B) \Omega_B \rangle \\
&= \int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \langle x\wedge (x\cdot ((a_J*\partial_\psi)(-\psi^\dagger\dot{\psi} + \dot{\psi}^\dagger\psi)))\Omega_B\rangle \\
&= \int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \langle x\wedge (x\cdot (-a_{J+}^\dagger\dot{\psi} + \dot{\psi}^\dagger a_{J+}))\Omega_B\rangle \\
&= 2\int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \langle x\wedge (x\cdot (\dot{\psi}^\dagger a_{J+})) \Omega_B\rangle \\
&= 2\int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \left\{\langle xx\cdot(\dot{\psi}^\dagger a_{J+})\Omega_B\rangle - \underbrace{\langle x\cdot(x\cdot(\dot{\psi}^\dagger a_{J+}))\Omega_B \rangle}_{=0}\right\} \\
&= 2\int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \frac{1}{2}\langle x\left(x\dot{\psi}^\dagger a_{J+} - \dot{\psi}^\dagger a_{J+}x\right)\Omega_B\rangle \\
&= 2\int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \frac{1}{2}\langle a_{J+}\Omega_B x^2\dot{\psi}^\dagger - a_{J+}x\Omega_Bx\dot{\psi}^\dagger \rangle \\
&= 2\int d^3x\rho \sum_J a^J \frac{1}{2}\langle a_{J+}x\left( x\Omega_B 
 - \Omega_B x)\right) \dot{\psi}^\dagger\rangle \\
&= 2 \sum_J a^J a_{J+} * \left(\int d^3x \rho x\wedge (x\cdot \Omega_B)\dot{\psi}^\dagger \right)\\
&= 2\mathcal{I}(\Omega_B)\dot{\psi}^\dagger
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the fact that $\mathcal I$ is its own adjoint, whence
$$
    \hat\partial_\psi\langle\Omega_B\mathcal I(\hat\Omega_B)\rangle
    = \hat\partial_\psi\langle\mathcal I(\Omega_B)\hat\Omega_B\rangle
    = \hat\partial_\psi\langle\hat\Omega_B\mathcal I(\Omega_B)\rangle,
$$
exactly the expression you already computed.

It's straightforward to show that $\mathcal I$ is self-adjoint if you use the left and right contractions[1]
$$
    X_r{\rfloor}Y_s = \langle X_rY_s\rangle_{s-r},\quad
    X_r{\lfloor}Y_s = \langle X_rY_s\rangle_{r-s},
$$
for $X_r$ with grade $r$ and $Y_r$ with grade $s$ and with the convention that the projections are zero if the grade is negative. These can then be extend by linearity to arbitrary multivectors. Alternatively, they are *defined* by the identities
$$
    \langle A{\wedge} B\,C\rangle
    = \langle A\,B{\rfloor}C\rangle,\quad
    \langle A\,B{\wedge} C\rangle
    = \langle A{\lfloor}B\,C\rangle,
\tag{$*$}
$$
for *arbitrary* multivectors $A,B,C$.

I adopt the convention of using $X\cdot Y$ only when $X$ and $Y$ have the same grade.

Now, for bivectors $A, B$
$$
    A\cdot(x\wedge(x{\rfloor}B))
    = (A{\lfloor}x)\cdot(x{\rfloor}B)
    = -(x{\rfloor}A)\cdot(x{\rfloor}B),
$$
with the first equality from applying ($*$).
It's clear from this form that $A\cdot\mathcal I(B) = \mathcal I(A)\cdot B$.

---

[1] L. Dorst, *The Inner Products of Geometric Algebra*, in: L. Dorst, C. Doran, J. Lasenby (Eds.), Applications of Geometric Algebra in Computer Science and Engineering, Birkhäuser, Boston, 2002: pp. 35–46.